# Ocaml tax calculator hidden error

Tags: ocaml

```
let tax income brackets rates =
  let rec calc (income:float) (brackets: float list list) (rates:float list) (x:int) : float =
    if List.nth (List.nth brackets x) (0) > income then
      0.0
    else if List.nth (List.nth brackets x) (1) > income then
      income -. List.nth (List.nth brackets x) (0) *. (List.nth rates x) +. calc (income) (brackets) (rates) (x+1) in calc income brackets rate 0
    else
      List.nth (List.nth brackets x) (1) -. List.nth (List.nth brackets x) (0)*.(List.nth rates x) +. calc (income) (brackets) (rates) (x+1) in calc income brackets rate 0
```

;;

Edited the code, still the same error. I think I am using "in" incorrectly here. How do I denote that I want to use this implementation of my aux function calc in the recursive calls of it.

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: It says "Error: Syntax Error" on the characters of the 2 final semicolons

Answer (score 1):

Every `let` must be followed by `in`, except at the outermost level of a module.

Your auxiliary function definition `let rec calc ...` is not followed by `in`.

**Update**

At the outermost level of a module you can have this:

```
let name = expression
```

This defines `name` as one of the components of the module. This is the case for your function named `tax`.

Everywhere else, you can only have this:

```
let name = expression1 in expression2
```

This defines `name` as a local variable to be used in `expression2`. You are defining a local variable named `calc` but you have no expression in which you're using it.

**Update 2**

Here's an example that uses an auxiliary function to return a reversed list of all the odd numbers in a given list.

```
let revodd list =
    let rec aux sofar auxlist =
        match auxlist with
        | [] -> sofar
        | h :: t ->
            if h mod 2 = 1 then
                aux (h :: sofar) t
            else
                aux sofar t
    in
    aux [] list
```

Comment: Are you sure? When I put an "in" after the declaration of the aux method, I get a syntax error on the "in"

Comment: Yes I am sure. You might show the new code. I'm not sure what it actually looks like. Certainly you can't just add `in` to fix your problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand the use of "in" now. How should I indicate that I want to use the local variable calc in the recursive calls of calc? I updated the code in the original post

Comment: Now you have too many uses of `in`. You can only have one of them. There's nothing special to do to indicate a recursive call. Just use the name.